# Error message "unable to create new native thread" using SMB endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I'm getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` error during transfer of around 20 files using SMB endpoint.

Camel version 2.13.

The route itself is quite simple:

```
<route id="Filetransfer">
    <from uri="ftp://user@server//source/map?password=pwd&amp;include=fileA.*.csv|fileB.*.csv|fileC.*.csv|fileD.*.csv|fileE.*.csv|fileF.*.csv&amp;move=save&amp;consumer.delay=30000" />
    <log message="${routeId}: ${header.CamelFileName}" />
    <to uri="smb://domain;user@server/target/map?password=pwd"/>
</route>
```

When I check the number of threads in Hawtio dashboard the thread count is hitting a peak of 1000. The route executes correctly when only some small files are transferred. When some biggger 
files (>5Mb, >100.000 lines) are transferred, the route gives the error.

When I replace the SMB endpoint with a FILE endpoint like `<to uri="file:///tmp/camel"/>` the route also executes correctly, and all the files are transferred.

Splitting the file per line first, and then use the Append option in the SMB endpoint causes the same error.

What can I do to make the SMB endpoint work, regardless the size of the files?

Comment: In general when that `Error` happens is because the OS is refusing to create new threads for your application. Probably, some of your code is creating many many threads somewhere and not finishing them.

Comment: The problem I face is that I dont know where I can control the creation/ending of threads in a SMB endpoint in Servicemix.
I don't have this issue on a test-environment, but I dont't know where to look for differences.